# How to check for the date in a textbox and compare it to DateTime.Now in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, time, textbox

I have a windows form program that reads from txt files and displays them in a textbox, the output can be:

- `Test w/c 07/03/16 AT 21/04/2016`
- `AT 09/05/2016`
- `w/c 07/03/2016 AT 17/03/2016 w/c 25/04/2016`

I am loading 7 text files into it, some contain either 1, 2 or 3 dates.

How would I detect these dates and be able to output whether the dates detected are before or after DateTime.Now?

My code:

```
 string[] ModuleGeneral = new string[5];
 int i = 0;
 foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(Modules[ModuleNum]))
 {
      if (line != "") {
      string[] parts = line.Split(':');
      foreach (string part in parts)
      {
            switch (parts[0]) {
                 case "ASSIGNMENT":
                      ModuleGeneral[4] = parts[1];
                      break;
             }

private void gameDesign1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MAssignmentsBox.Text = moduleInformation[4];
```

Comment: regular expressions and `Date.TryParse`

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that your dates will be in a specific format (i.e. "MM/dd/yyyy","dd/MM/yy", etc.) then you can use a Regular Expression (via [`Regex.Matches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) to match them and then properly parse them in using the expected format using the [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method (since you know the exact format):

```
var input = "w/c 07/03/2016 AT 17/03/2016 w/c 25/04/2016";

// Find dates
var dates = Regex.Matches(input,@"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2,4}");

foreach(Match date in dates)
{
    // Use a placeholder to store your date
    DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy",null,DateTimeStyles.None,out d))
    {
            // The date was properly parse, so compare it
            if(d > DateTime.Now)
            {
                // Your date is larger, handle accordingly
                Console.WriteLine(d + " is greater than today");
            }
            else
            {
                // Your date is smaller, handle accordingly
                Console.WriteLine(d + " is less than today");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
         // Your date was in the wrong format, do something
    }
}
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhWzrs), which yields the following output :

```
3/7/2016 12:00:00 AM is less than today
3/17/2016 12:00:00 AM is less than today
4/25/2016 12:00:00 AM is greater than today
```

One of the issues here is that you seem to use both a two-digit and a four-digit year, so you would probably want to determine how to best handle that. If you can expect the dates to use either a 2 or 4 digit year, you can adjust your parsing string to attempt both options :

```
var formats = new ["dd/MM/yyyy","dd/MM/yy"];
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date.Value,formats,null,DateTimeStyles.None,out d))
{
     // Omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Date.TryParse parses a string and returns true if the string was successfully parsed into a date.

Then you can just check the date parsed if it is bigger or smaller than DateTime.Now